# Are these sizeWithFont codes equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

```
[self sizeWithFont:font];

[self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999,9999)];
```

I want to make sure that sizeWithFont simply uses very large size and for all practical purpose call  sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a) for `sizeWithFont:`:

> Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered with the
>   specified font on a single line.

So, as long as the width will never be over 9999, the result should be the same.

Edit:
Note that `sizeWithFont:` doesn't subsequently call `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` (or `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode` (at least on iOS 6).

To test this, I created a category for `NSString` and replaced `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` and `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode`. The 2 methods didn't get called when using `sizeWithFont:`.